# How can I get more polycount in the viewport without crashing?

Tags: displacement, polycount

Not really even sure what question to ask? I am working with elevation/heightmap data and converting it into a 3dMesh for personal purposes. My current process is adding a grid with a displacement modifier using a heightmap texture PNG.  My problem is that my texture is massive (30032x24658), and I can't keep the detail I am wanting. I understand that the amount of polygons this would generate is upwards of a billion and that is a bit absurd, but I am looking for a solution whether it be by Blender or another software to keep as much detail as possible in the model without cutting it up. Currently I am having to scale my resolution down to just above 3% (5618x4613 subdivisions)
Note: I know a better PC would help, but I do not have to render this out, but edit mode and exporting is required. Just maybe looking to change some settings or something to optimize.

Comment: just my personal opinion here: you should ask in a different way. You should tell us your endgoal and then we can help you. Often you can set higher polycount only for certain areas so in total you will have less, but as usual: it depends... so please give us more detailed example of what you are trying to achieve. And why don't you want to cut it?

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the comment. Yeah I've done a ton of research since posted. I'm creating a 3d model of an elevation map to export it to .STL. I only have 32GB of RAM to work with. even set undo steps to 0 and memory limit to 10.